# mysql_insert_id() stopped working after PHP update

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.3, mysql-insert-id

I am preparing to update a live web server from PHP 5.2.12 to 5.3.5.  In preparation, I have performed the update on a second server which is a mirror of the live one ("dev" server).  Both servers are using FreeBSD, and both used ports to install PHP and MySQL.  The live server is using MySQL 5.0.89, the newly upgraded dev server is using 5.1.54.

The following code executes as expected on the live server (PHP 5.2.12/5.0.89), returning the value of the AUTO_INCREMENT row that was just inserted.  This function is part of a database class that is used throughout the site, where "$this->_private['cn']" is the resource link.

```
 public function insert ($sql=false) {
    @mysql_select_db($this->_private['db_name'],  $this->_private['cn']);
    $res = null;            
    if (false !== $sql) {
        $query_obj = mysql_query($sql, $this->_private['cn']);
        if ($query_obj)
            $res = mysql_insert_id($this->_private['cn']);
    }
    return $res;
}
```

On the dev server (5.3.5/5.1.54), the return is zero.  Note - not null (which is returned if the query fails), but ZERO.  I can look at the table and verify that a new row has in fact been inserted, and the auto increment field has properly advanced.  The field value is currently at 121288, so it is well within PHP's integer range.  I've even re-created the class's code on a simple page and get the same result.  mysql_error() indicates no failures.  Error reporting is set to E_ALL, not a peep there.

ARGH!  Any ideas?

Comment: You should file a bug report. Sounds like you have done your due diligence and it doesn't appear to be your fault. It is probably already in the tracker, and may even have a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [bug](http://www.mail-archive.com/php-bugs@lists.php.net/msg140923.html) which recommends following your query with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()`

Comment: That does appear to be relevant, thank you.  However, I note that one of the comments there states "a bug this obvious would have been detected a long time ago"... I'd have to concur.  Yet... here I am.  :)  If nothing else, that gives me a workaround for now.  Not excited about having to add another query in my class, but then I've never been clear as to how mysql_insert_id() gets it's information; maybe the additional query winds up being equivalent in resource consumption.

Comment: I'd imagine PHP's mysql_insert_id() is just a wrapper for MySQL's last_insert_id()